Groovy resolve a variable with a 'manufactured' variable
I'm sure I'm over simplifying this, but I want to resolve a variable with another manufactured variable. This is a generic sample of my syntax.
 def sMonth     = 'Jan'
 def aVar   = 'Month'
 def bVar   = 's' + aVar
 println("${bVar}")

Ultimately, I want bVar to resolve to 'Jan', but understandably it's resolving to 'sMonth'. How can I get Groovy to resolve to the variable I created?
I've tried many variations of the println, but they all keep resolving to sMonth.

This very likely is a X-Y-problem. Either other tags are missing
(e.g. Groovy is used as an scripting language inside another product) or
this is used to build a scripting environment in itself.  Assuming this
is the case, please describe your actual problem for what you thought of
this to be a solution.  This does not work, because it does not need to.

In a script like this, there is no access to local bindings.  The only
chance here is to "promote" the bindings to fields and the access those
by their name.  E.g.
@groovy.transform.Field
def sMonth = 'Jan'
def aVar   = 'Month'
def bVar   = 's' + aVar
println(this."$bVar")
println(getProperty(bVar))

